# Strange padding in iPad Safari when using <a href> and <input> in HTML

Tags: html, ipad, safari, padding

I am building a system for dictation excercises in danish, specifically for the iPad.
Up until now, I have been testing in gnome, and the pages look fine, but when I finally got my iPad, something is wrong.

I am building clickable sentences with sound like this:

```
<audio id="audiotag6" src=diktat02/gaaet.m4a preload="auto"></audio>
<a href="javascript:play_sound('audiotag6');">The sun had   <input type="text" name="word6" autocomplete="off"/>  ned, </a>
<audio id="audiotag7" src=diktat02/koelig.m4a preload="auto"></audio>
<a href="javascript:play_sound('audiotag7');"> and the air was  <input type="text" name="word7" autocomplete="off"/>  klar, </a>
```

In chrome and IE the text appears fine like:

The sun had [ input box ] and the air was [ input box ]

But on the iPad it appears like a [tab] is inserted before every line of "a href=":

```
       The sun had [ input box ]            and the air was [ input box ]
```

This is my first big project with a homepage, and this problem is quite a setback for me, since the whole idea is for this to work on the iPad - please help..

Comment: Is it the " ned, " and " klar, " somehow? Or is that a typo in your example?

Comment: Input elements [aren't allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) inside a elements.

Answer (score 1):

I found that removing the audio tags fixes the issue. You could use the following layout:

```
<body>
<audio id="audiotag6" src=diktat02/gaaet.m4a preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="audiotag7" src=diktat02/koelig.m4a preload="auto"></audio>

<form>
<a href="javascript:play_sound('audiotag6');">The sun had   <input type="text"       name="word6" autocomplete="off"/>  ned, </a>
<a href="javascript:play_sound('audiotag7');"> and the air was  <input type="text" name="word7" autocomplete="off"/>  klar, </a>
</form>
</body>
```

Also, you should not put the anchor elements inside the form element but outside of a field type element.. it may work but it is not semantically accurate :)

EDIT:

After thinking some more about how this could be done in a semantically friendlier way, I put thsi together:

```
<audio>
  <source src="diktat02/gaaet.m4a" id="audiotag6" preload="auto" type="audio/m4a" />
  <source src="diktat02/koelig.m4a" id="audiotag7" preload="auto" type="audio/m4a" />
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio> 

<form onsubmit="play_sound('audiotag6');">
The sun had   <input type="text" name="word6"  autocomplete="off"/>  ned, 
<input type="submit" value="Play" />
</form>

<br />
<br />

<form onsubmit="play_sound('audiotag7');">
and the air was  <input type="text" name="word7" autocomplete="off"/>  klar,
<input type="submit" value="Play" />
</form>
```

This way you avoid the links, the audio tags are set up at once, the play mechanic of the sentences is clearer, and the javascript is less indirect. Of course, you will decide on how to implement this based on your own preferences and I don't think mine is the best solution in any event :)

Hope this helps.